# Detecting closed immersions on fibers

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, ac.commutative-algebra, homological-algebra, arithmetic-geometry

Let $R$ be a dvr and $f : X\to S$ a universally closed morphism of $R$-schemes.
Assume $X$ and $S$ are $R$-flat and universally closed.

> If the special fiber of $X\to S$ is a closed immersion, is $X\to S$ a closed immersion?

**remarks**

- My guess is "no", but I'm looking for a counterexample (I can imagine something where $f$ crashes a locus contained in the generic fiber to a point).
- Namely, I expect "no" for an answer because I see no reason why $f$ should have to be a monomorphism (unless one also assumes $f$ is a closed immersion on generic fibers, which I am not assuming). I'd expect some example such that for some $s\in S$ the fiber $f^{-1}(s)$ is nonempty and larger than $\kappa(s)$-point.
- I can believe $f$ is unramified. What I expect should fail is the monomorphism part.
- A silly example of a map that is a monomorphism on special fibers but not globally a monomorphism can already be, calling $K$ the fraction field of $R$ $$f : \text{Spec}(K)\coprod \text{Spec}(R) \to\text{Spec}(R)$$
  induced by the ring map $R\to R\times K$, the identity on the first factor and the inclusion on the second. Clearly $f$ is the identity (hence a closed immersion) on special fibers, but it is not a monomorphism globally since the fiber over the generic point $\eta\in\text{Spec}(R)$ is two copies of $\eta$ and not one.
- **What I'm looking for** is a neat non-silly example of a geometric flavor (say $X$ and $S$ connected, of dimension $\ge 2$, perhaps $f$ of relative dimension $\ge 1$ with geometrically connected fibers). In the first example above $\text{Spec}(K)\coprod\text{Spec}(R)$ is not universally closed, so this is not an example directly relevant to the question. The second example above, if correct, should answer the question in the negative, as expected. I'd prefer some example for which one can (at least generically) "draw a picture".

Comment: Welcome new contributor.  Here is a better example than the one that I wrote earlier.  Let $t\in R$ be a uniformizing element.  Let $S$ be $\text{Spec}(R)$, and let $X$ be $\text{Spec}(R[x,y]/\langle x^2,ty-x\rangle)$.

Comment: @JasonStarr Yes I agree this is a good example. Thank you so much!

Comment: @JKR In the second example in the question, $f$ is not integral because $\mathbb{Z}_{(p)}^h$ is not integral over $\mathbb{Z}_{(p)}$.

Comment: @JasonStarr In your example, $f$ is not universally closed (the special fiber is $\mathbb{A}^1$).

Comment: @LaurentMoret-Bailly. You are correct.  I meant to take Spec of the $R$-algebra $R\oplus \text{Frac}(R)x$, where $x^2$ is zero.  I thought I found a cute presentation; but of course that $R$-algebra is not finitely presented.

Comment: @LaurentMoret-Bailly I agree $\mathbf{Z}_{(p)}^h$ is not  integral over $\mathbf{Z}_{(p)}$, but $\alpha$ is one element of $\mathbf{Z}_{(p)}^h$ that satisfies $\alpha^2-\alpha+p=0$ (namely, the one root of $T^2-T+p$ lifting $1$). The polynomial $T^2-T+p$ is in $\mathbf{Z}_{(p)}[T]$ and it is monic, so $\alpha$ is integral over $\mathbf{Z}_{(p)}$. Since it is an integral element over $\mathbf{Z}_{(p)}$ generating $A$ as a $\mathbf{Z}_{(p)}$-algebra, isn't $A$ even finite? Of course it is *not at all true* that every element of $\mathbf{Z}_{(p)}^h$ is integral over $\mathbf{Z}_{(p)}$.

Comment: @JKR Oh, right, I misread the definition. But then $A$ is just $\mathbb{Z}_{(p)}[T]/(T^2-T+p)$ whose special fiber has two points. Which root you pick is irrelevant: if $\beta$ is the other root, then $\mathbb{Z}_{(p)}[\alpha]=\mathbb{Z}_{(p)}[\beta]$ since $\alpha+\beta=1$.

Comment: @LaurentMoret-Bailly Oh, you're absolutely correct, I'll remove this example.
I'm wondering if, if one further assumes both $X$ and $S$ are reduced, the question has a positive answer. The proposed example and some variations of it are all non-reduced examples. I'll ask a new question with these additional assumptions, so as to avoid overburdening this question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am just posting my comment as an answer, mostly to correct the mistake identified by @LaurentMoret-Bailly.

The property of being universally closed depends only on the underlying reduced scheme.  Thus, there are counterexamples coming from a nilradical that is quasi-coherent, yet not coherent.

For one example, let $S$ be $\text{Spec}(R)$ and let $X$ be Spec of the $R$-algebra $R\oplus \text{Frac}(R)x$, where $x^2$ is zero.  The morphism from $X$ to $S$ is a universal homeomorphism, thus universally closed.  The morphism of closed fibers is an isomorphism, hence it is a closed immersion.  Yet the morphism of generic fibers is projection from the dual numbers over Spec of $\text{Frac}(R)$, and this is not a closed immersion.

Comment: Thank you very much! This is also an example of a *flat* surjective universally closed map between flat universally closed schemes over $R$, that is residually an isomorphism, but not globally an isomorphism. I'm wondering if these are the only possible examples for this phenomenon. Of course if $f$ was locally finitely presented, they'd be ruled out and $f$ would indeed be an isomorphism (it would be finite flat of degree one, hence finite étale of degree $1$ since an isom on special fiber). I have asked a more targeted question [here](https://mathoverflow.net/q/397233)